# Request-URI Too Large need to use serialized with post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

You can see the site I'm trying to troubleshoot at niors.com

After I click generate more than once it gets the error (Request-URI Too Large)

Here is the javascript used

```
function generate_clicked()
{
    var formData = $('#form').serialize();
    var url='process.php?';
    url+=formData;


    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json; charset=x-user-defined");
      }
    }).done(function ( data ) {
        try{
            $('#preview').val(data.css);
            $('#my_iframe').srcdoc = data1;
            }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        document.getElementById("my_iframe").src = data.live_preview_html_page;
    });

}
```

How can I change that so that it POST and not uses GET which I assume is causing the problem?

I would have to change these to post to right?

```
$text_color = $_REQUEST['text_color'];
$link_color = $_REQUEST['link_color'];
$link_hover_color = $_REQUEST['link_hover_color'];
$title_color = $_REQUEST['title_color'];
```

I also have this in process.php

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header('Content-type: application/json');

$returnJSONObject = array();
$returnJSONObject['status'] = false;
$returnJSONObject['message'] = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax call to `POST` and add the form data to the POST payload:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST', // specifying POST
    data: formData, // adding data
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json; charset=x-user-defined");
  }
})
```

Comment: How do I add form data to POST payload?

Comment: See the line where I commented 'adding data'

Comment: I tried but I must be having to edit something else, please check your email!